# What is the best way for using PayPal adaptive payment API with C++?

Tags: php, c++, api, paypal, payment

I am trying to find the best way to use **PayPal** adaptive payment using API.
Our process is running on `Linux`, written in `C++`.

Since there is no `SDK` for `C++`, I have 2 options:

1. Use a direct API (SOAP, REST)
2. Create a `php` + `SDK` that will handle it externally.

Any thoughts about the right solution ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the SDK doesn't exist in C++, you can either redirect the user to a webpage from the process, or use a C++ RESTful library, like [restbed](https://github.com/Corvusoft/restbed) to do the trick.

Comment: Tnx, I will try to use REST library instead, seems like the only solution :(